# Как прервать работу AJAX запроса

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть некий скрипт, работает на аяксе, жмем кнопочку, идет запрос.

Задача: прервать работу запроса получив то, что уже отработалось в php скрипте.

Серверная сторона выдает данные из бд.

Используется prototype.

Для чего это нужно: бывает запрос занимает очень много времени (5-10 минут), хочется дать пользователям возможность прерывать работу скрипта, получив то, что уже есть, а не ждать еще пол часа.

Comment: Вы наверняка знакомы с постраничным выводом. Как вариант, можно ставить лимит на выборку из базы.

Comment: Знаком, наверняка, но меня интересует именно такая вариация :)

Comment: вру, я его писал на prototype.

Comment: это скорее со стороны сервера надо решать. т.е. посылать еще один ajax запрос, который будет ставить флаг, а функция для первого запроса этот флаг будет проверять и отваливаться с частичным результатом. тонкости реализации на php не подскажу.
правда возникают дополнительные трудности с обработкой остального, остальное придется запрашивать повторно, но это видимо преодолеть можно, если задасться целью...

Comment: еще один аякс запрос послать не получается, он терпеливо ждет в очереди, пока отработает первый.

Comment: вообще-то работает. правда у браузеров есть ограничение на два одновременных коннекта (у некоторых  настраивается или больше по дефолту), но если второй коннект свободен, то запрос пошлется. другое дело, что гарантировать чтоб будет свободный коннект в любой момент времени довольно сложно. Правда есть методы борьбы с данным поведением и прочие воркараунды http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997159/consecutive-ajax-requests-without-jquery-js-library


все равно, imho, проблема именно серверная, либо рефакторить зависающую функцию, либо ждать пока она отработает, js тут слабо помогает...

Answer (score 1):

На скорую руку как то так

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/ajaxtest.php");
request.send();
request.onprogress = function(e){
    request.responseText // временные данные
};
request.onload = function(e){} // запрос завершился

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function(){
    request.abort(); // убиваем запрос
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Если клиент прервет соединение, то пхп-скрипт прекратит работу. В данном случае нужно прервать работу JS-скрипта, который посылает запрос. И наличие flush() обязательно, иначе ничего не выведет, а тупо прекратиться работа скриптов.

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
```

в начале скрипта и скрипт будет прерыватся по мере прерывания соединения JS с сервером.

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай типа так?

>function stopit()
>{
>ignore_user_abort(false);
>}

и потом онклик вешать эту функцию?

Comment: оу.. это php функция, это здорово, но что написать в js части?

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    var myajax=$.ajax(){
        ....
    }

    $("#somebutton").click(function(){
        myajax.abort();
    });


не уверен, что сработает, но попробовать стоит. А так поему, нужно химичить в php-скрипте.

Comment: ну я пробовал функwию делать и вешать на онклик, тело функции
>    myajax.abort();
фаербаг сообщает

>myAjax is not defined  

>myAjax.abort();

Comment: пробовал - не работает, либо я не допонял о чем он.